# Advanced dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an advanced drop down menu and I got stuck in a problem that when I click on any item inside the menu the menu is closed I am using bootstrap 4.2.1 As there is in the picture, the red areas are places that I do not want when clicking on them to close the drop down menu And the green areas are what I want when they are clicked on
[Advanced dropdowne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEWmd.png)

Why do I want it like this because there is something going on in the drop down menu See the picture for more details
[Advanced dropdowne image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUSo9.png)
The complete code used to do this is attached For the record, it looks incorrect when it is displayed on the site because it is designed for the computer and not for mobile

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            direction: rtl;
            text-align: right;
        }

        body {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .navbar-nav {
            padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .icon-link:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
        }

        .scrollbar {
            max-height: 320px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        /* width */
        .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 5px;
        }

        /* Track */
        .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Handle */
        .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #888;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        /* Handle on hover */
        .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #555;
        }
        .navbarDropdownHover:hover{
            background-color: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.1);
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        .navbarDropdownFocus:focus {
            background-color: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.1);
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        span{
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
        <a class="navbar-brand"
            href="#">
            <img src="#"
                width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
           Web site name
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active" title="home">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                        href="#"><svg
                            style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true"
                            focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="home" class="svg-inline--fa fa-home fa-w-18"
                            role="img" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M280.37 148.26L96 300.11V464a16 16 0 0 0 16 16l112.06-.29a16 16 0 0 0 15.92-16V368a16 16 0 0 1 16-16h64a16 16 0 0 1 16 16v95.64a16 16 0 0 0 16 16.05L464 480a16 16 0 0 0 16-16V300L295.67 148.26a12.19 12.19 0 0 0-15.3 0zM571.6 251.47L488 182.56V44.05a12 12 0 0 0-12-12h-56a12 12 0 0 0-12 12v72.61L318.47 43a48 48 0 0 0-61 0L4.34 251.47a12 12 0 0 0-1.6 16.9l25.5 31A12 12 0 0 0 45.15 301l235.22-193.74a12.19 12.19 0 0 1 15.3 0L530.9 301a12 12 0 0 0 16.9-1.6l25.5-31a12 12 0 0 0-1.7-16.93z">
                            </path>
                        </svg> home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" title="link">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><svg
                            style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true"
                            focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="folder-plus"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-folder-plus fa-w-16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M464,128H272L208,64H48A48,48,0,0,0,0,112V400a48,48,0,0,0,48,48H464a48,48,0,0,0,48-48V176A48,48,0,0,0,464,128ZM359.5,296a16,16,0,0,1-16,16h-64v64a16,16,0,0,1-16,16h-16a16,16,0,0,1-16-16V312h-64a16,16,0,0,1-16-16V280a16,16,0,0,1,16-16h64V200a16,16,0,0,1,16-16h16a16,16,0,0,1,16,16v64h64a16,16,0,0,1,16,16Z">
                            </path>
                        </svg> link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" title="link">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                        href="#"><svg
                            style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true"
                            focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="store-alt"
                            class="svg-inline--fa fa-store-alt fa-w-20" role="img" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M320 384H128V224H64v256c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h256c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V224h-64v160zm314.6-241.8l-85.3-128c-6-8.9-16-14.2-26.7-14.2H117.4c-10.7 0-20.7 5.3-26.6 14.2l-85.3 128c-14.2 21.3 1 49.8 26.6 49.8H608c25.5 0 40.7-28.5 26.6-49.8zM512 496c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V224h-64v272z">
                            </path>
                        </svg> link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<ul class="navbar-nav navbarDropdownHover">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" title="Services">
                    <a class="nav-link ropdown-toggle navbarDropdownFocus" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><svg
                            style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" class="gb_Ve" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="currentColor"
                                d="M6,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM16,6c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2s2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2zM12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2z">
                            </path>
                        </svg></a>
                    <div class="scrollbar dropdown-menu p-3" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight">

                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center collapsed"
                                data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1"><svg style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                                    data-prefix="fas" data-icon="globe" class="svg-inline--fa fa-globe fa-w-16"
                                    role="img" viewBox="0 0 496 512">
                                    <path fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M336.5 160C322 70.7 287.8 8 248 8s-74 62.7-88.5 152h177zM152 256c0 22.2 1.2 43.5 3.3 64h185.3c2.1-20.5 3.3-41.8 3.3-64s-1.2-43.5-3.3-64H155.3c-2.1 20.5-3.3 41.8-3.3 64zm324.7-96c-28.6-67.9-86.5-120.4-158-141.6 24.4 33.8 41.2 84.7 50 141.6h108zM177.2 18.4C105.8 39.6 47.8 92.1 19.3 160h108c8.7-56.9 25.5-107.8 49.9-141.6zM487.4 192H372.7c2.1 21 3.3 42.5 3.3 64s-1.2 43-3.3 64h114.6c5.5-20.5 8.6-41.8 8.6-64s-3.1-43.5-8.5-64zM120 256c0-21.5 1.2-43 3.3-64H8.6C3.2 212.5 0 233.8 0 256s3.2 43.5 8.6 64h114.6c-2-21-3.2-42.5-3.2-64zm39.5 96c14.5 89.3 48.7 152 88.5 152s74-62.7 88.5-152h-177zm159.3 141.6c71.4-21.2 129.4-73.7 158-141.6h-108c-8.8 56.9-25.6 107.8-50 141.6zM19.3 352c28.6 67.9 86.5 120.4 158 141.6-24.4-33.8-41.2-84.7-50-141.6h-108z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg><span> Change language </span>

                            </div>

                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center collapsed"
                                data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2"><svg style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                                    data-prefix="fas" data-icon="adjust" class="svg-inline--fa fa-adjust fa-w-16"
                                    role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M8 256c0 136.966 111.033 248 248 248s248-111.034 248-248S392.966 8 256 8 8 119.033 8 256zm248 184V72c101.705 0 184 82.311 184 184 0 101.705-82.311 184-184 184z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg><span>Dark mode</span></div>
                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center"><svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                                    fill="none">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M20 0H492C503.046 0 512 8.9543 512 20V492C512 503.046 503.046 512 492 512H20C8.9543 512 0 503.046 0 492V20C0 8.9543 8.9543 0 20 0ZM312.25 183.25C320.417 183.25 328 183.833 335 185V142C330.333 139.667 323.5 138.5 314.5 138.5C286.667 138.5 265.167 150.583 250 174.75L249.25 143.5H204.25V414H250.5V222C261.333 196.167 281.917 183.25 312.25 183.25Z"
                                        fill="currentColor"></path>
                                </svg><span>System R</span></div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="card card-body py-2 px-4 collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                            <a class="dropdown-item text-center"
                            href="#"
                            tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"> language 2<svg
                                style="width: 32px; height: 16px; color: green;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="check-circle"
                                class="svg-inline--fa fa-check-circle fa-w-16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                <path fill="currentColor"
                                    d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z">
                                </path>
                            </svg></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center"
                            href="#"
                            tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">English language</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card card-body py-2 px-4 collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch dropdown-item" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="darkSwitch">Normal mode/ Dark mode</label>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight">
                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center"><svg
                                    style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="store-alt"
                                    class="svg-inline--fa fa-store-alt fa-w-20" role="img" viewBox="0 0 640 512">
                                    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M192 208c0-17.67-14.33-32-32-32h-16c-35.35 0-64 28.65-64 64v48c0 35.35 28.65 64 64 64h16c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32V208zm176 144c35.35 0 64-28.65 64-64v-48c0-35.35-28.65-64-64-64h-16c-17.67 0-32 14.33-32 32v112c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h16zM256 0C113.18 0 4.58 118.83 0 256v16c0 8.84 7.16 16 16 16h16c8.84 0 16-7.16 16-16v-16c0-114.69 93.31-208 208-208s208 93.31 208 208h-.12c.08 2.43.12 165.72.12 165.72 0 23.35-18.93 42.28-42.28 42.28H320c0-26.51-21.49-48-48-48h-32c-26.51 0-48 21.49-48 48s21.49 48 48 48h181.72c49.86 0 90.28-40.42 90.28-90.28V256C507.42 118.83 398.82 0 256 0z">
                                    </path>
                                </svg><span>Emergency calls</span></div>
                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center"><svg
                                    style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"
                                    data-prefix="fas" data-icon="play" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-play fa-w-14">
                                    <path fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M424.4 214.7L72.4 6.6C43.8-10.3 0 6.1 0 47.9V464c0 37.5 40.7 60.1 72.4 41.3l352-208c31.4-18.5 31.5-64.1 0-82.6z"
                                        class=""></path>
                                </svg><span>Video clips</span></div>
                            <div class="py-2 px-4 bd-highlight icon-link rounded text-center"><svg
                                    style="width: 32px; height: 32px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="question-circle"
                                    class="svg-inline--fa fa-question-circle fa-w-16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                                    <path fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M504 256c0 136.997-111.043 248-248 248S8 392.997 8 256C8 119.083 119.043 8 256 8s248 111.083 248 248zM262.655 90c-54.497 0-89.255 22.957-116.549 63.758-3.536 5.286-2.353 12.415 2.715 16.258l34.699 26.31c5.205 3.947 12.621 3.008 16.665-2.122 17.864-22.658 30.113-35.797 57.303-35.797 20.429 0 45.698 13.148 45.698 32.958 0 14.976-12.363 22.667-32.534 33.976C247.128 238.528 216 254.941 216 296v4c0 6.627 5.373 12 12 12h56c6.627 0 12-5.373 12-12v-1.333c0-28.462 83.186-29.647 83.186-106.667 0-58.002-60.165-102-116.531-102zM256 338c-25.365 0-46 20.635-46 46 0 25.364 20.635 46 46 46s46-20.636 46-46c0-25.365-20.635-46-46-46z" />
                                </svg><span>Common questions</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a solution on many sites, I finally found it I have read and seen an article written by CodingNepal on codingnepalweb [Click here to view it](https://www.codingnepalweb.com/advanced-drop-down-menu-javascript/)
quite simply it was reviewing the advanced drop-down menu that he code it But it caught my attention how he switched the dropdown menu to appear and disappear using javascript and css I simply tried to apply this trick but I was struggling with Bootstrap So I removed some codes As you can see the following code line:

```
<a class="nav-link ropdown-toggle navbarDropdownFocus" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdown" href="#">
```

Become like this

```
<a class="nav-link adv-dropdown" href="#">
```

and

```
<div class="scrollbar dropdown-menu p-3" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

Become like this

```
<div class="scrollbar dropdown-menu p-3 wrapper" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

I simply simplified the code and added some classes which is:

`.adv-dropdown` in the button and `.wrapper` in the dropdown-menu with the help of javascript I wrote

```
const adv_dropdown_menu = document.querySelector(".adv-dropdown");
        const menu_wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
        adv_dropdown_menu.onclick = (()=>{
        menu_wrapper.classList.toggle("show");
        tooltip.classList.toggle("show");
      });
```

It simply works :)